# How to use FOSTwitterBundle to call Twitter API

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed FOSTwitterBundle and set up key on Twitter.

I create this Action:

```php
public function twitterFirstAction(Request $request)
{
    $twitter  = $this->get('fos_twitter.service');
    $authURL  = $twitter->getLoginUrl($request);
    $response = new RedirectResponse($authURL);
    return $response;
}
```

It redirects to twitter and redirected back to `twitterSecondAction()`

```php
public function twitterSecondAction(Request $request)
{
    $twitter = $this->get('fos_twitter.service');
    // now what
}
```

I checked the session, everything is fine. But now I get confuse how to make an API call. For example, list user's followers.

Comment: do you remember your mistake? I have the same error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238366/symfony2-fostwitterbundle-no-oauth-tokens-retrieved).

Comment: I'm calling $accessToken = $twitterService->getAccessToken($request); on different page request. I just save the $accessToken on session and use it whenever I need it. But, now it works just like on the docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FOSTwitterBundle has `fos_twitter.api` service which is [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/kertz/twitteroauth/blob/master/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php) class which allows you to do get, post and delete requests.

So your second action can look like this:

```
public function twitterSecondAction(Request $request)
{
    $twitter = $this->get('fos_twitter.api'); //
    $idsOfFollowers = $twitter->get('followers/ids');
}
```

Please see [twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) for possible actions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I get error Undefined index: oauth_token when using $this->get('fos_twitter.api') on diferrent page request

Comment: Hmm, check those links: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/25 and https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3651